# Split and Recombine Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I currently have a tensorflow `Dataset` with a number of batches (Number of batches would be variable, but divisible by 4). I want to take out every 4th batch to use as testing and the rest as training, but I have yet to encounter an elegant solution. A simplified visual example of desired results:

```
Dataset = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12]
train = [b1,b2,b3,b5,b6,b7,b9,b10,b11]
test = [b4,b8,b12]
```

Most solutions on train-validation-test splits regarding `Dataset`s use a combination of `Dataset.take()` and `Dataset.skip()`, as they don't mind splitting the data somewhere down the middle. If I were to use this solution, however, it would require me computing the size of the dataset, run an ugly loop over it with multiple `take()`s and `skip()`s, then collecting the results and concatenating them together into a new `Dataset`. Is there no better way to select intervals of batches in a tensorflow dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be achieved through a combination of `enumerate()`, `filter()`, and `map()`, similar to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671472/8479618).

Toy example:

```
list(
    Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(12))
    .batch(2)
    .as_numpy_iterator()
)
```

Output:

```
[array([0, 1]),
 array([2, 3]),
 array([4, 5]),
 array([6, 7]),
 array([8, 9]),
 array([10, 11])]
```

Solution on toy example:

```
list(
    Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(12))
    .batch(2)
    #solution starts here
    .enumerate() 
    .filter(lambda i, data: (i+1)%4 !=0)
    .map(lambda i,data: data)
    #solution ends here
    .as_numpy_iterator()
)
```

out:

```
[array([0, 1]), 
 array([2, 3]), 
 array([4, 5]),
 array([8, 9]),
 array([10, 11])]
```